# Primefaces FileUpload error remains even after correct upload

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, upload

I am using primefaces3.5 fileupload control.  When I upload a wrong format file then it shows a error message "Wrong format etc".  After that when I upload a correct format file then it uploads fine but does not remove the error message.
While searching I found [this solution](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23853) on primefaces forum but it is also not working.

How can I remove the error message on subsequent uploads?

Here is my code

```
<p:fileUpload id="fu"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(DOC|DOCX|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlsx|pdf)$/"
    onstart="loadingCursor();" oncomplete="simpleCursor();"
    multiple="false" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="52428800"
    showButtons="false"
    fileUploadListener="#{documentInsertController.uploadPListener}"
    label="Browse"
    invalidSizeMessage="File size exceeds limit 45 MB "
    value="#{documentInsertController.file}" auto="true"
    invalidFileMessage="Invalid file type.Only doc,ppt,xls and pdf files allowed."
    >
    <h:message id="docMSG" for="fu"></h:message>
</p:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me with PrimeFaces 3.5:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        fileuplaod_wgt.buttonBar.find("button.cancel").bind("click", function (e) {
            clearInvalidFileMsg();
        });
    });

    function clearInvalidFileMsg() {
        fileuplaod_wgt.uploadContent.find("tr.ui-state-error").remove();
    }
</script>
```

And I've added `widgetVar="fileuplaod_wgt"` in the `p:fileUpload`. Then `cancel` button works and removes invalid files.

It is not a permanent solution. Just a workaround until it will be fixed within PrimeFaces itself. Check: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3652

Comment: its working ..but it affects design of select one menu component